# Navigation bar is hidden but not allowing header button click in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, navigation, navigationbar

I am trying to hide the navigation bar in SwiftUI, able to hide the navigation bar but it disables user-interaction of my header button.
I use the below code to hide the navigation bar.

`.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true).navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitle("")`

The above code work in another view but not working in Dashboard.
When I move to another view and come back to the dashboard then the navigation bar hides properly.

I also try this
`NavigationLink(destination: MainTabBarView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true).navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitle(""), isActive: $isPushHome)` but no luck.

Comment: you want completely remove the navigationbar ? from all views included the mainView(Dashbaord) ?

Comment: and what do you mean with "user-interaction of my header button" ?

Comment: Yes @Osman, I want to completely remove it. I add my custom menu button on top of the screen but the user is not able to access it due to the navigation bar.

Comment: ok have you tried to hide and add a toolbar ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have also another options in the toolbar.

Please try the following code :

```
   var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack{
            Text("Content").font(.largeTitle)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Test")
                })
            }
        })
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it is not showing Test button, I don't know why.

Comment: ok please show the code, one solution is that you don't have a navigation view 
please try to add a navigation view. I just edit my question.

Comment: I added a navigation view to my login screen, and I am facing an issue on the dashboard.
I added the title also to confirm navigationBarTitleDisplayMode changed or not.
Checkout code
http://prnt.sc/1vfgff2
This is Output
http://prnt.sc/1vfgkt5

Comment: please add the toolbar and all the stuff to the ZStack

Comment: Actually, I hide the navigation bar for that view, then why it is still there?
If I move to another view and come back to Dashboard main view then it will be hidden. 
SO problem is that the first time it is not hidden but the second time it will hide.

Comment: ok understand and how do you navigate to the main view ?

Comment: ```NavigationLink(destination: MainTabBarView(),isActive: $isPushHome)``` this the code